# How to access data "deep" inside a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am getting a JSON response from a web service as follows into a NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                             options:0
                                                                               error:NULL];
```

If I dump the output of the NSDictionary it looks correct like this

```
2017-10-06 10:11:46.097698+0800 NWMobileTill[396:33294] +[ShopifyWebServices fetchAllCollections]_block_invoke, {
    data =     {
        shop =         {
            collections =             {
                edges =                 (
                                        {
                        cursor = "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NTI4NTY3MTcsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiI0NTI4NTY3MTcifQ==";
                        node =                         {
                            description = "";
                            id = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzQ1Mjg1NjcxNw==";
                        };
                    },
                                        {
                        cursor = "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NTI4NTkwODUsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiI0NTI4NTkwODUifQ==";
                        node =                         {
                            description = "Test Collection 1";
                            id = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzQ1Mjg1OTA4NQ==";
                        };
                    },
                                        {
                        cursor = "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NTU0OTMwMDUsImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiI0NTU0OTMwMDUifQ==";
                        node =                         {
                            description = Sovrum;
                            id = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzQ1NTQ5MzAwNQ==";
                        };
                    },
                                        {
                        cursor = "eyJsYXN0X2lkIjo0NTU0OTMzODksImxhc3RfdmFsdWUiOiI0NTU0OTMzODkifQ==";
                        node =                         {
                            description = Badrum;
                            id = "Z2lkOi8vc2hvcGlmeS9Db2xsZWN0aW9uLzQ1NTQ5MzM4OQ==";
                        };
                    }
                );
                pageInfo =                 {
                    hasNextPage = 0;
                };
            };
        };
    };
}
```

I need to access the "description" attribute deep inside this structure and I cannot figure out how to do it.

I tried the following but it crashes

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse) {
    NSLog(@"jongel %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"]);
}
```

Comment: Your code goes down one level, what about the rest?

Comment: but it crashes even on that one level, so I must be doing something wrong and if I cannot get one level down I don't even know how to get deeper into the structure.

Comment: As @Bilal meant to point out, `fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse` is a dictionary, not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bilal's answer is right. This might be a bit easier to read:

```
NSArray *edges = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"data"][@"shop"][@"collections"][@"edges"];
for (NSDictionary *edge in edges) {
    NSString *description = edge[@"node"][@"description"];
    NSLog(@"description = %@", description);
}
```

Comment: This works exactly as I needed it to work, I am just trying to understand how you got so deep with so little code

1, you created an array of dicts from the original dict, one for each level
2, you are looping each dict , but how do you know you are at the right level?
is that it?

Comment: Looking at the output you can determine the structure of the original dictionary, `fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse`, which is a dictionary containing a dictionary, containing a dictionary, etc..

Comment: I never create any arrays. I just access the data contained in `fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse`.

Comment: but you create NSArray *edges, is that only to keep track of the indexes as you go deeper into the original Dict?

Comment: I create a local variable `edges` which is a pointer to the array. Then I create a local variable `edge` which points to elements of the array, but I never create any arrays myself.

Answer (score 1):

`fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse` is a `Dictionary` not an `Array`. Try this.

```
NSDictionary *fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse = nil;
NSDictionary *data = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"data"];
NSDictionary *shop = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"shop"];
NSDictionary *collections = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"collections"];
NSArray *edges = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"edges"];

// Or a shorter version 
// NSArray *edges = fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse[@"data"][@"shop"][@"collections"][@"edges"];

for (NSDictionary *edge in edges) {
    NSString *cursor = edge[@"cursor"];
    NSDictionary *node = edge[@"node"];
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to say `fetchAllCollectionsJSONResponse` is a dictionary not an array.